# Ionic 2 - Open external pdf inside my app

Tags: ionic2

I have some pdf file links on my app, and I wanna the user be able to open/read then inside my app. Is it possible? Is there any easy way to do that? Thanks!

EDIT:
Until now, I'm using regular link, like this:

```
<a href="{{conta.link_conta}}" *ngIf="conta.link_conta">
```

But in that case, it opens on the external browser (chrome for android, in my test). I would like to open it inside my own app, kinda like facebook, instagram, twitter and some other apps do

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code to show?

Comment: @gerdi updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: I am searching for a same solution. Can you please let me know whether you found any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't try it, but can't you use InAppBrowser plugin
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Set the target as '_self',

Comment: tried that in a example project for that plugin (https://github.com/techiediaries/ionic2-inappbrowser-example), but still opens on chrome!